# How to convert .ods to latex?

Tags: tables

When I use calc2latex I receive the error message "BASIC Runtime Error: Object Variable not set"

Using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: .ODS is not converted to LaTeX? It is very ODD... ;-)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: The OD(D)S are against it ;-)

Comment: This does sound more like a unrelated-to-TeX issue. I think this might be better suited for askUbuntu, but the question will need to be clearer.

Comment: Have a look at [this blog post](https://latexforhumans.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/converting-spreadsheets-to-latex/).  The author devises two alternatives to `calc2latex`.

Comment: you can try also [odsfile](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/odsfile?lang=en) package

Comment: Following the @HenriMenke, comment I found a relatively acceptable solution using *gnumeric* at AskUbuntu: http://askubuntu.com/a/502855/325029. So for anybody passing by this question...